how to handle ORA-17820: The network adapter could not establish the connection error
I want catch db error when trying to connect to it
My code:
private static String getValueFromDB(String dbConnection,String dbUsername,String dbPassword,String condition,String field){
        String data="";
        try {


            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbConnection, dbUsername, dbPassword);
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM NDTBNODE WHERE " + condition);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, licenseKey);
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();while (resultSet.next()) {
                // Process the result set
                if(field.equals("DC_ID"))
                    data=String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt(field));
                else
                    data=resultSet.getString(field);
            }
        } catch (java.sql.SQLRecoverableException e) {
        loggerS.error("Recoverable error occurred while connecting to the database: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
        loggerS.error("SQL Exception occurred while interacting with the database: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
        return data;
}

I tried putting the Exception class still the same result.
the exception i'm getting:
May 12, 2024 12:32:34 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection connect
INFO: I:thread-1 main entering args (oracle.jdbc.internal.AbstractConnectionBuilder$1@44a59da3)
May 12, 2024 12:32:34 PM oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol connect
INFO: U:thread-1 main traceId=5276D6EE. 
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: ORA-17820: The network adapter could not establish the connection.
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonNetException(T4CConnection.java:1398)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:991)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:1157)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:104)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:825)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:651)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:683)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:230)
at com.iono_tech.SDK_Service.SdkServiceApplication.getValueFromDB(SdkServiceApplication.java:408)
at com.iono_tech.SDK_Service.SdkServiceApplication.checkForId(SdkServiceApplication.java:435)
at com.iono_tech.SDK_Service.SdkServiceApplication.checkForTheFile(SdkServiceApplication.java:490)
at com.iono_tech.SDK_Service.SdkServiceApplication.main(SdkServiceApplication.java:562)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: ORA-17820: The network adapter could not establish the connection. 
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-17820/at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:779)
at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:707)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:938)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:327)
at
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connectNetworkSessionProtocol(T4CConnection.java:3185)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:926)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: 
at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.establishSocket(TcpNTAdapter.java:325)
at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:222)
at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:327)
at
oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.executeConnOption(ConnStrategy.java:1144)
at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:718)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: no further information
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:682)
at
java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:973)
at
oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.initializeSocketChannel(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:246)
at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.connect(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:203)
May 12, 2024 12:32:34 PM oracle.jdbc.diagnostics.Diagnostic dumpDiagnoseFirstFailure

i don't want to fix it, i want to handle it

Not enough info

please supply the stack trace

I don't know what this means: i don't want to fix it, i want to handle it. You can re-throw exception out of your method. (loggerS.error("Recoverable error occurred while connecting to the database: {}", e.getMessage()); then add throw e;

@Alex stackoverflow won't let me add it

@life888888 it means even though i know it will make an exception i just want to ignore it rather than making it halt the app

@Mhd adnan Al kharfan,  it halt the app , meaning more other exception , you don't catch it. add catch (Throwable t) {      loggerS.error("Something Wrong while interacting with the database: {}", t.getMessage()); }

I don't quite understand what is exception class, that is why I asked trace log. Can you recognize from log what the exception you have? oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection is not an exception, it is a class where exception occurs. You catch sql exceptions only, but it can be some other exception. If you want to catch ALL exceptions use catch(Throwable ex) {...}

@life888888 still halt the app and i can't catch it

INFO: I:thread-1 main throwing
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: ORA-17820: The network adapter could not establish the connection. (CONNECTION_ID=G7RCvfq5Tkum2f5MVV3xkw==)
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-17820/
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonNetException(T4CConnection.java:1398)

Still not the full stack trace and you need to post it in the question, not as a comment. Your strategy of only logging the exception message is not helping you. You need to log the stack trace

@g00se i hear you loud and clear but github won't let me

@g00se it's the closest i was able to get

Are you able to prove that db is running?

@g00se yes, but i close the network on purpose as test scenario for when it's close.
as i said i only want to handle the error rather than fix it

You might want to look at doing that in checkForTheFile but for now, do the experiment of adding, in getValueFromDB, as a final exception block catch(Throwable t) { t.printStackTrace(); } What happens?

@g00se same error, it don't handle it.

You're probably going to have to come up with a network-oriented 'probing' routine that succeeds/fails as the driver connection succeeds/fails and execute that first

@g00se i tried to isolate it but it's doing the same, there's no fail/success but straight up exception

That's a fail since you seem to be in doubt ;)

@g00se yeah it's a fail but not handled one

Well I told you what I think you could do about that here

@g00se if there's a better solution it would be better to be honest like it should handled by try-catch, i don't why it still halt the app even with them

it would be better to be honest I really don't know what you mean by that. The error is not in your code, it's in the driver. If the driver can't connect to the server, it's game over

@g00se but there must be a way to handle the exception it produces
